# Is there a "drop in" commenting system for webapps, allowing users to log in using Facebook or Twitter

Tags: web-applications

I'm looking for some middleware that handles adding a "comment" system on to arbitrary pages in a webapp, that allows the user to use their Facebook or Twitter (or perhaps Google and other similar systems) to leave the comment.

This sort of functionality exists as plugins for all sorts of web apps ([socialee](http://www.shotwellcompany.com/addons/socialee) for ExpressionEngine, various plugins for WordPress) but I'm looking for a system that can be used anywhere.

The closest example would be Facebook's [Comments Box plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) but of course that *only* works for Facebook accounts. I want to give the user more freedom to use other accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://disqus.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are http://disqus.com/ and http://intensedebate.com/